# Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently programming a launcher in Visual Studio that gets the version history from a MySQL server. I have run into an issue where I cannot connect to the database if I use a public login for the database. If I use the root login I can connect on my local machine but no other. This is what I am using with subins to protect my data:

```
"server='serverip';user='severusername';password='serverpassword';database'databasename'"
```

If I use the root password, it will connect on my local computer. If I use my godaddy hosting database, it will also work on any computer. The MySQL server I am connecting to is on my local computer and running WAMP. Does anyone know a way to get it to work? My user has full permissions. This is programmed in Visual Studio using Visual Basic.

Comment: Are you not missing `=` in between database and databasename? And probably user called username really doesn't have permissions (root has like in most built in configurations)

Comment: MySQL logins can be restricted to IP address.  Query the mysql.users table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding 2 cases of my user. One with a host of localhost and another with a host of 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you have a typo:

```
database'databasename'
```

Should that not be:

```
database='databasename'
```

Also, it could be that godaddy does not allow remote connections for MySQL so when you try to connect from your local WAMP installation to their remote MySQL server the connection is denied. This is more than likely the case as the bandwidth cost for this can become quite huge very quickly. You should however be able to run things in the shared hosting environment using localhost as the server/hostname.

Comment: I am not trying to connect to godaddys MySQL. I am trying to connect to my own remotely. I was saying that it works when I use godaddys but not when I use my own.

Comment: @JacobBashista try to use localhost instead of the server ip.

Comment: @JacobBashista When you say that you are trying to connect to your own remotely, you must understand that by default MySQL is not configured to allow remote connections. You could google something like "wamp mysql allow remote connection" to resolve this.

Comment: @JacobBashista in PHPMyAdmin or in the MySQL console on the local machine running WAMP, try to log in as the public user then do `SHOW GRANTS;`. What permissions exist in the output?